# add bidirectionnal relation many to many symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a many to many relation between two entities in my bundle.
I want to make this relation bidirectionnal.
The problem is that after that I will add a request on one entity that will use the other as a parameter :

this is in the repository of the entityA

```
public function findType($type,$superior)
{

$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

  $qb->select('a')
     ->from('xxxBundle:Profile', 'a')
     ->where('a.type = :type')
     ->andwhere('a.entityB = :superior')
     ->setParameter('superior', $superior) 
     ->setParameter('type', $type);


  $entities=$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
  return $entities;
}
```

I get the following exception

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 84 near 'entityB = :s': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.
```

Any ideas?????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216470/symfony2-and-doctrine-error-invalid-pathexpression-must-be-a-statefieldpathe

Comment: so what does the `$type`variable look like?

Comment: I fixed this error by following the link suggested by @cheesemacfly but the problem now is that the entities are not saved into the database.