# Error with subquery in doctrine2 query builder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this query with a subquery:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $subquery = $query;
    $subquery
        ->select('f.following')
        ->from('ApiBundle:Follow', 'f')
        ->where('f.follower = :follower_id')
        ->setParameter('follower_id', $id)
    ;

    $query
        ->select('c')
        ->from('ApiBundle:Chef', 'c')
        ->where('c.id <> :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
    ;
    $query
        ->andWhere(
            $query->expr()->notIn('c.id', $subquery->getDQL())
        );

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

And I get this error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 116 near 'f, ApiBundle:Chef': Error: 'f' is already defined.
```

I can't find the cause of the error, the alias f is defined only one time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is about objects and references in PHP.

When you do `$subquery = $query;`, `$query` being an object, you simply have `$subquery` pointing to the same value.

> A PHP reference is an alias, which allows two different variables to
> write to the same value. As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't
> contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object
> identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object.
> When an object is [...] assigned to another
> variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of
> the identifier, which points to the same object.

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

It means in your code that when you write this:

```
$subquery
    ->select('f.following')
    ->from('ApiBundle:Follow', 'f')
    ->where('f.follower = :follower_id')
    ->setParameter('follower_id', $id)
;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
$query
    ->select('f.following')
    ->from('ApiBundle:Follow', 'f')
    ->where('f.follower = :follower_id')
    ->setParameter('follower_id', $id)
;
```

So when at the end you call:

```
$query->andWhere(
        $query->expr()->notIn('c.id', $subquery->getDQL())
    );
```

You are using 2 times the same object pointed by 2 different variables (`$query === $subquery`).

To solve this issue, you can either use:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$subquery = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
```

Or the [`clone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) keyword:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$subquery = clone $query;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but now the error is: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 74 near 'following FROM': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

Comment: @m4t1t0 can this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216470/symfony2-and-doctrine-error-invalid-pathexpression-must-be-a-statefieldpathe

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share my solution which requires ORM mapping:

Following entities are mapped like this:
Event 1:M Participant

```
Participant class
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="KKB\TestBundle\Entity\Event", inversedBy="participants")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="event_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
private $event;

Event class
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="KKB\TestBundle\Entity\Participant", mappedBy="event", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $participants;


class EventRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{

public function getEventList($userId)
{

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');
    $subquery = $this->createQueryBuilder('se');

    $subquery
        ->leftJoin('se.participants', 'p')
        ->where('p.user = :userId')
        ;

    return $query->where($query->expr()->notIn('e.id', $subquery->getDQL()))
        ->setParameter('userId', $userId)
        ;
}

}
```