# Symfony Doctrine select

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have following entities:

Application:

```
/**
 * Care worker
 *
 * @var CareWorker
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sme\CareWorkerBundle\Entity\CareWorker", inversedBy="application", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
private $careWorker;
```

And Careworker:

```
/**
 * Application
 *
 * @var Application[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Sme\CareWorkerBundle\Entity\Application\Application", mappedBy="careWorker", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 *
 */
private $application;
```

I am trying to retrieve the careworker field from the application using this query:

```
 $qb=$em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('a.careWorker')
        ->from('SmeCareWorkerBundle:Application\Application','a')
    ;
    $query=$qb->getQuery();

    $query->getResult();
```

I am getting this query exception

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 9 near 'careWorker FROM': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

Can you please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 and Doctrine - Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216470/symfony2-and-doctrine-error-invalid-pathexpression-must-be-a-statefieldpathe)

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of care worker entities?  You will need to select from careworker instead of application.  If you need to filter by application then join it and apply your where clauses.

Comment: @Cerad I need to get the list of Applications, so I can join it later with Careworkers, so then I can join it further.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$qb=$em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('a.careWorker')
        ->from(Sme\CareWorkerBundle\Entity\Application\Application::class,'a')
    ;
    $query=$qb->getQuery();

    $query->getResult();
```

be careful to first arg of "from" functio

Answer (score 0):

To get all applications and its corresponding careWorker:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('a')
    ->addSelect('cw')
    ->from('SmeCareWorkerBundle:Application\Application', 'a')
    ->leftJoin('a.careWorker', 'cw')
;

$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Between Careworker and Application I have one to many relation. I need to get all applications first and then all corresponding CareWorker.