# Symfony 4 InnerJoin Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression

Tags: php, symfony

I have an entity Image that is in a ManyToMany relation with a Tag entity. I am trying to get the images that are related to the Tag i am fetching from the database in an inner join request as shown bellow:

```
public function findOneByNameWithImages(string $name)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->addSelect('t.images')
            ->leftJoin('t.images', 'images')
            ->where('t.name = :name')
            ->setParameter('name', $name)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

But when i execute the query i get this error:

```
    [Semantical Error] line 0, col 12 near 'images FROM App\Entity\Tag': 
    Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216470/symfony2-and-doctrine-error-invalid-pathexpression-must-be-a-statefieldpathe

Comment: No, it's not but i found the solution i made a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to add the select at the alias images not the t.images:

```
public function findOneByNameWithImages(string $name)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->leftJoin('t.images', 'images')
            ->addSelect('images')
            ->where('t.name = :name')
            ->setParameter('name', $name)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```