# Create a select distinct request with symfony 5

Tags: symfony, request, doctrine

In **symfony 5**, with doctrine I want to create a request to select distinct type.
So, I have made the following code:

```
 /**
     * @Route("/hometest", name="hometest")
     */
    public function index2()
    {
        $lesservices = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Services::class)->findAll();
        $em = $this->getdoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT distinct serv.souscategorie FROM App\Entity\Services serv');
        $services = $query->getResult();
        return $this->render('home/indextest.html.twig', array ('servicesliste' => $lesservices, 'distinctscat' => $query));
    }
```

But, I am getting this error :

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 21 near 'souscategorie': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
```

In fact, souscategorie is a relation field and if I put a string field at his place everything goes right.

Do I have to make a join request to have my souscategorie results ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You already have `souscategorie` in each `$service` entity. Can you elaborate more your question (add the twig  and the entity) to be able to more help you?

Comment: What's the relation between `serv` and `souscategorie`?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT serv.souscategorie FROM App\Entity\Services **AS** serv

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting a relation field, this might be your problem.

By searching [your error](https://www.google.com/search?q=Error%3A%20Invalid%20PathExpression.%20Must%20be%20a%20StateFieldPathExpression) i found out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14216878/4820276) which could help you solve your query without having to join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IDENTITY(serv.souscategorie) ...
```